# XSD complexContent restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

I found following example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_empty.asp).

```
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:complexContent>
```

I was searching through many documentations but still don't get it: When a complexContent has no "mixed" attribute the element does not have any text node and therefore does not need any data type. But why the `<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">` ? As I understood this does absolutely nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that the above complex content snippet (or that on the linked page) is correct according to the XML Schema specification, so that your concerns make sense. If you try it with an XML Schema validation engine, it should throw an error. A complex type with complex content (element-only or mixed) cannot be derived by restriction from a simple type.

A complex type with empty content and an attribute can be defined as follows:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Just for completeness: It is also technically feasible to derive a complex type that must have "empty content" (mind the quotes) from a simple type, however, this must be done by extension, and the simple type must be the singleton space containing the empty string, so as not to allow any content. The obtained complex type will then have simple content that must be the empty string -- so it is actually not, strictly speaking, empty content, but it does behave as such when validating instances.

```
<xs:simpleType name="empty">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="empty">
            <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```